# Eagerly lazy loading routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

App level router

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dist', redirectTo: '/landing' },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/landing', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'manage-herd', loadChildren: './manage-herd/manage-herd.module#ManageHerdModule' }
];
```

Sub router

```
{
  path: '', 
  component: ManageHerdShellComponent, 
  children: [
    { path: ''},
    { path: 'cow-group-select', component: GroupSelector, outlet: 'comp1' }
  ]
}
```

Navigating to the top level manage-herd route works, when I attempt to navigate to the child route it fails with error 'Cannot match any route'

1. It worked before I tried to set up eager lazy loading
2. There is a `router-outlet` in the HTML
3. I have the `router.navigate` that looks like this:

   ```
   this.router.navigate([{outlets: {comp1:['cow-group-select']}], {relativeTo: this.route});
   ```

Comment: Isn't eager lazy loading just... loading?

Comment: I could have worded this better. How about 'asynchronously loading the modules that aren't required for landing page the user sees'.

Comment: Then that's just lazy loading!

Comment: preloading them then!
https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb#.n3r12bomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, I've fixed my problem but I'd like to document what I've found for posterity.

```
 { path: '', component: ManageHerdShellComponent}, 
 { path: 'manage-herd', component: ManageHerdShellComponent,
```

Adding path: 'manage-herd' back in the lower routing module fixed my issue of navigating to my child components. My other lower routing module didn't require this. The first one had a router outlet directly in the template, the other had it's router outlet in a nested component's template. Complex issue it seems.